# How to create a Firebase short dynamic link

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm successfully creating a Firebase dynamic link in Java on Android. My code to do so is in a button click listener.

```
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse("https://www.mycompany.com/"))
            .setDomainUriPrefix("https://mycompany.page.link/test")
            .setAndroidParameters(
                new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.mycompany.app")
                    .setFallbackUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.mycompany.com/"))
                    .setMinimumVersion(1)
                    .build())
            .buildDynamicLink();

        Uri dynamicLinkUri = dynamicLink.getUri();
        shareDynamicLink(dynamicLinkUri);
    }
});

public void shareDynamicLink(Uri dynamicLink)
{
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    String msg = "Check this out: " + dynamicLink;
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(shareIntent);
}
```

This sends a LONG dynamic link that works just fine. Now I'd like to shorten the link, so I replaced the 'shareDynamicLink' method with this code.

```
public void shareDynamicLink(Uri dynamicLink)
{
    Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
        .setLongLink(dynamicLink)
        .buildShortDynamicLink()
        .addOnCompleteListener(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getActivity()), new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task)
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    // Short link created
                    Uri shortLink = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getShortLink();
                    Uri flowchartLink = task.getResult().getPreviewLink();

                    Log.e("DynamicLink", "shortLink: " + shortLink + System.lineSeparator());
                    Log.e("DynamicLink", "flowChartLink: " + flowchartLink + System.lineSeparator());

                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    String msg = "Check this out: " + shortLink;
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    startActivity(shareIntent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to share event.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

This second method produces an error that I don't understand.

```
"400: Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link:
https://mycompany.page.link/test?afl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mycompany.com%2F&amv=1
&apn=com.mycompany.app&ibi=com.mycompany.app&ifl=https%3A%2F%2F
www.mycompany.com%2F&isi=963543827&ipfl=https%3A%2F%2F
www.mycompany.com%2F&link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mycompany.com%2F
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]
```

What am I missing here? This seems like it should work.

Note: I don't need the long dynamic link, just the short one. I tried changing the onClickListener as follows.

```
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Task<ShortDynamicLink> dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse("https://www.mycompany.com/"))
            .setDomainUriPrefix("https://mycompany.page.link/test")
            .setAndroidParameters(
                new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.mycompany.app")
                    .setFallbackUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.mycompany.com/"))
                    .setMinimumVersion(1)
                    .build())
            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnCompleteListener(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task)
                {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Uri shortLink = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getShortLink();
                        Uri flowchartLink = task.getResult().getPreviewLink();

                        Log.e("DynamicLink", "shortLink: " + shortLink + System.lineSeparator());
                        Log.e("DynamicLink", "flowChartLink: " + flowchartLink + System.lineSeparator());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.e("DynamicLink", "Link failed: " + task.getException().getMessage() + System.lineSeparator());
                    }
                }
            });

    }
});
```

But I still get the same 400 error.

```
400: Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link:
https://mycompany.page.link/test?afl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mycompany.com%2F&amv=1
&apn=com.mycompany.app&ibi=com.mycompany.app&ifl=https%3A%2F%2F
www.mycompany.com%2F&isi=963543827&ipfl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mycompany.com%2F
&link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mycompany.com%2F
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds this, my problem stemmed from a misunderstanding of how programmatically generated links work vs. predefined links. In my case I was trying to use a pre-defined link from the Firebase console ("https://mycompany.page.link/test") as the PREFIX for my generated link. That caused some sort of confusion on the back end when I tried to shorten it. I still don't understand exactly what it didn't like, but point is it failed.

So the solution for generating links was to use only the base prefix from the Firebase console - .setDomainPrefix("https://mycompany.page.link/"). Using that I can create either ".buildShortDynamicLink()" or "buildDynamicLink()".

The link I created in the Firebase console ("http://mycompany.page.link/test") can only be used verbatim -- no need to generate anything. Just put it in a text message literally and you're done.

Comment: Hi, I have remove the /test from the domainUriPrefix but still giving me the error 400: Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to use the longer version at all, or only the short one? If so, does it work if you use `.buildShortDynamicLink()` instead of `.buildDynamicLink()` in your `onClick(...)` method without the conversion in `shareDynamicLink(...)`?

Comment: I only want the short one, but it won't let me use .buildShortDynamicLink() because that requires an anonymous function within the anonymous function of the onClick().

Comment: Added refactored onClick() handler above. Still getting the 400 error.

Comment: I changed  .setDomainUriPrefix("https://mycompany.page.link/test") to  .setDomainUriPrefix("https://mycompany.page.link/") and it no longer fails. But the link I made in my Firebase control panel includes the "/test" so how am I supposed to be able to use that?

Comment: I thought of that too, but then again some Google documentation/examples on the web contain a "/something" in their `domainUriPrefix`. 

Does the following link work? `mycompany.page.link/test/`? Note the trailing slash.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think the problem was a fundamental misunderstanding on my part.  The dynamic link I created in the Firebase console can and must be used verbatim -- no need to build a link in code at all.  That link is NOT a "prefix" URI.  Creating something in code MUST use the BASE URI as its "prefix".  I think I was mixing metaphors.

Comment: Happy to hear that it works now. I think you should answer your own question with your findings in a really clear way and accept it as "the answer" so that other people that stumble on this issue will find their way. :-)